# Unable to run the package chemfig with TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, chemfig

I want to use the package chemfig to draw chemical structures. I am using Texmaker. Whenever I try to run the chemfig package I get the following error message:

```
! I can't find file `simplekv.tex'.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.57 \fi
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.57 \fi
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I ran the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{A*5(-B=C-D-E=)}

Incomplete rings are also possible

\chemfig{A*5(-B=C-D)}
\end{document}
```

I also ran the MWE on Overleaf and it complied successfully, thus my conclusion that it must be TexMaker that is the problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is, please, the structure of your chemical formula? It have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LaTeX extension `chemfig` uses the extension `simplekv` (simple key-value system for the options of the commands).

In your case, LaTeX can't find the file `simplekv.tex`. Maybe this extension is not installed on your system or the installation is corrupted. You should uninstall the extension `simplekv` (if it's installed) and reinstall it.

If you use MikTeX (the most frequent distribution on Windows), you can do that with the "MikTeX Console".

If you use TeXLive (widely used in the Linux world), you may use `tlmgr`.

Comment: Thank you! Everything is working after installing the extension